FastAPI SQL Post Request receiving 500 Error Internal Server Error
I'm using FastAPI and SQL Alchemy trying to make a post request to my "Player" table in my Postgres SQL Database. However, my player table raises the following error:
(https://i.sstatic.net/0k9ulaYC.png)
500: Internal Server Error: Object of type AttributeError is not JSON serializable
Which confuses me, as my Questions and Choices table work perfectly well without any issues. I tried to create another similar table but keep receiving the same issues, could someone please help?
This is my models.py:
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database import Base


class Players(Base):
    __tablename__ = "players"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(String, index=True)
    # hashed_password = Column(String)
    # is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    # items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")

class Questions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    #id (Eg: 69420)
    #question = Have u seen my scrunchie?
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    question_text = Column(String, index=True)
    # answer = Column(String)

class Choices(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'choices'

    # id
    #choices: A: yes, B: No
    #is_correct: True/False
    #question_id: foreign key to questions table 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    choice_text = Column(String, index=True)
    #column with answer either True/False
    is_correct = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    #Links back to question (Eg: 69420)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("questions.id"))

    


# class User(Base):
#     __tablename__ = "users"

#     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

And here is my main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends, Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Annotated

from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

import models, crud, schemas
from database import engine, SessionLocal
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from exception_handlers import request_validation_exception_handler, http_exception_handler, unhandled_exception_handler
from middleware import log_request_middleware

app = FastAPI()

app.middleware("http")(log_request_middleware)
app.add_exception_handler(RequestValidationError, request_validation_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(HTTPException, http_exception_handler)
app.add_exception_handler(Exception, unhandled_exception_handler)

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

class PlayerBase(BaseModel):
    user_name: str
#Model rep the choice user makes and whether its True/False
class ChoiceBase(BaseModel):
    choice_text: str
    is_correct: bool

#Model rep the possible choices a user can make A, B, C, D
class QuestionBase(BaseModel):
    question_text: str
    choices: List[ChoiceBase]
    

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

db_dependency = Annotated[Session, Depends(get_db)]

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    return PlainTextResponse(str(exc), status_code=400)

@app.post("/players")
async def create_player(user: PlayerBase, db: db_dependency):
    try:
        db_player = models.Player(user_name=user.user_name)
        db.add(db_player)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_player)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=e)
        
# @app.get("/users/", response_model=list[schemas.User])
# def read_users(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
#     users = crud.get_users(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
#     return users

@app.post("/questions")
async def create_questions(question: QuestionBase, db: db_dependency):
    db_question = models.Questions(question_text=question.question_text)
    print("This works for some stupid reason")
    db.add(db_question)
    db.commit()
    #Refresh
    db.refresh(db_question)
    for choice in question.choices:
        #quick filter for db choice, look into model. choices
        db_choice = models.Choices(choice_text=choice.choice_text, is_correct=choice.is_correct, question_id=db_question.id)
        db.add(db_choice)
    db.commit()

@app.get("/questions/{questions_id}")
async def read_question(question_id: int, db: db_dependency):
    result = db.query(models.Questions).filter(models.Questions.id == question_id).first()
    if not result:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Question is not found')
    return result

@app.get("/choices/{question_id}")
async def read_choices(question_id: int, db: db_dependency):
    result = db.query(models.Choices).filter(models.Choices.question_id == question_id).all()
    if not result:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Choices is not found')
    return result

I've tried error handling techniques to narrow down the problem and searching other forums, I havent been able to find a similar issue or solution

You need to reduce your example down to a minimal reproducible example. I feel if you do that you will find your bug, as an AttributeError indicates you're trying to access or assign something that doesn't exist.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

did you run code in console to see error messages? It may show more details and it can explain what is the problem. Current error suggests that you try to write something as JSON but JSON can keep only primitive objects (like text, integer, float) and it doesn't know how to write some complex object.

it seems it try to send some error as JSON - and this suggest me that it can be in except Exception as e: raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=e) because there is place where errors always appear, and where HTTPException may try to send this error so it may try to convert it to JSON. And then I check code in try - and I see you create Player(...) but it seems you have model Players() with char s at the end - and maybe this is the problem.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Your exception handler inside create_player swallows any exception regardless of what that exception is, and then tries to serialize that exception as the JSON body of a HTTP response:
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=e)

This means that you never get the proper error bubbling up - which makes it very hard to do proper development.
You should always be specific in what exceptions you want to catch, instead of catching any exception and then exposing that exception to anyone calling your API (which is also a bad idea, as you can end up leaking information that you didn't intend to make public).
If you remove the whole try and except part, you'll probably discover that you've mistyped the name of your model: it's named Players and not Player which is what you're trying to access, so you get an AttributeError when trying to reference Player in your models module.
Either rename your Players model to Player (and in that case, rename all your other models from plural to singular if they represent singular entries as well), or change your reference to refer to the correct model name:
db_player = models.Players(user_name=user.user_name)


Thank you so much! ok that was very silly of me but it works now! I'll definitely be more cautious of exeption handling in the future
